# $(document).ready not firing? Possibly related to jsps

Tags: jquery, html, google-app-engine, jsp

I have the following code to bring up a jqplot graph in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
alert("javascript working!");
$.jqplot('statgraph', [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]]);
});
</script>
```

And the following imports in the head (yes, the imports are before the ready() function):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/lib/jquery/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/lib/jquery/jquery.jqplot.css" />
```

I am running these from a jsp with google app engine, but it doesn't seem to call the ready() function correctly. When I paste this code into a fresh html page, it works. Is the issue with the jsp then? Thanks!

Comment: unusual place for storing the javascript file. why not use a CDN or place the file under WebContent/scripts and try access it

Comment: That's very strange, putting the jquery folder in the same directory as my main html page made it work. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: The reason is that the script wasn't even being included before.  In its new location, it can be included.  This was never a problem with $(document).ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work locally, because you can access WEB-INF on your own computer, but not deployed, because you cannot access WEB-INF remotely.  Put the js files somewhere else in your war folder.  The war folder will be mapped to /, so if you have war/javascript.js, just refer to it as /javascript.js .